# Pharo: how to open a Transcript if none is open

Tags: pharo, morphic

I would like to know whether a Transcript window is visible, and if not to open one.

Since the model behind a Transcript is a PluggableTextMorph I thought about collecting all those which represent Transcripts with

> PluggableTextMorph allInstances select: [ :e| e model = Transcript ]

This is all nice, returns a bunch of objects. However, it's not clear which of these is visible. Probably a beginner Morphic question... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there is a better way, but you can definitely use this:

```
World submorphs
  detect: [ :m | m model = Transcript ]
  ifNone: [ Transcript open ]
```

or

SystemWindow allInstances
      detect: [ :m | m model = Transcript ]
      ifNone: [ Transcript open ]

The thing is that I've tried to do

```
ThreadSafeTranscriptPluggableTextMorph allInstances detect: ...
```

but for some reason morph is still alive even if window is closed